Blindfolded prisoners


Spacing: edge, 1.5m, prisoner, 2m, prisoner, 1m, prisoner, 1m, prisoner, 1.5m, prisoner, 1m, prisoner, 0.5m, prisoner, 2.5m, edge
Seven Blindfolded prisoners are pushed onto a hanging platform, which is open at both the ends. Below, there is a large pool of volcanic lava which is hot enough to instantly kill upon contact. The metal surface of the platform is steaming hot, so the prisoners must constantly walk at a minimum speed of 0.5m/s, to ensure that their legs are not burnt. Two prisoners walking in opposite directions, upon collision will reverse direction but continue to walk at the same speed. It is obvious that eventually all of them will fall off the platform. The platform is 11m long, and the initial positions of the prisoners are as shown in the figure, but their initial directions (i.e. left or right) may be different. Solve the following questions running through the prisoner's mind.
Question 21
Clearly, the total time taken for all the prisoners to fall off the platform depends on the initial orientation of each of the prisoners. Prisoner A notices that if they orient themselves in a particular manner, the total time can be maximized. What is the maximum possible total time?

A) 11
B) 13
C) 17
D) None of these


I get 13 but the answer is supposed to be D. Why?
Source:

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B5-GsYZi9MQFWTdERkZEVXYyRjg.
Internet Archive.


Very related: Maximum time for ants to fall off stick

Not that it is necessary for any voter to justify their vote, but to me a -5 score with zero improvement suggestions seems like a very uncommon response from our community. Maybe someone is using downvotes as a substitute for a VTC(dupe)?

It's very easy to find an initial configuration that takes longer than the largest of the given options.

If everybody faces to the right, the last person to fall is the leftmost prisoner, after walking 9.5m in 19 seconds.

Clearly, the maximum time cannot be less than this, and since all of A-C are, the correct choice must be D.

Oh gosh how did miss that, well what I'd they all don't face the same direction. With that constraint is it possible that a maximum time can be calculated?

The maximum time will be the same for any configuration as long as the leftmost person faces right. While the identities of the people switch, the overall positions are no different if they bounce off each other vs pass through each other. For each person, someone will fall off at time 2x their initial distance to the edge. Making the leftmost person face right means that someone will fall off in 19s, and everyone else falls off earlier.

@kagami Great observation. Interestingly, the maximum time could be increased with a slight tweak to the problem, if collisions are allowed not only between prisoners moving in opposite directions, but also ones moving in the same direction. By moving faster than 0.5m/s, the leftmost person could walk into the back of the second-leftmost person moving at 0.5m/s just before they fall, allowing them to walk all the way back and stay on the platform longer than 19s, even though they're moving faster than the minimum!

Somehow I couldn't figure this out, even though the same reasoning is used un physics where you derive the kinetic gas equation, you ignore collisions cause they don't make a difference
